# how to .net svc https connect android

Tags: android, wcf, android-ksoap2

I want to connect to data services after specific web with Android. Service. Svc and working as https.

Encode and get the following error.

I'll be waiting for your answer. .

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//I'm not sure this is it true. METHOD_NAME, NAMESPACE, URL, SOAP_ACTION 

    static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTableUpdateVersionByTableName";
    static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SecureFlight.Core.Domain.Synchronization";
    static final String URL = "https://app.xxx.com/IntSecureFlight/SFInternal.svc";
    static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IOperationSvc/GetTableUpdateVersionByTableName";
    TextView sonuc;
    EditText tableName;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sonuc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tableName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tableName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                Request.addProperty("tableName", tableName.getText().toString());

                SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
                soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);


                try {
                    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;


                    if (result != null) {

                        sonuc.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connections"+e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        });

    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
         java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeread(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.access$200(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:55)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:532)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readln(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1279)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readServerResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1351)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1644)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:117)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseCode(ServiceConnectionSE.java:103)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:193)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
at com.example.soapsdeneme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the cause of errors?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SOAP_ACTION is "http://tempuri.org/IOperationSvc/GetTableUpdateVersionByTableName"
2. NAMESPACE is "http://tempuri.org/"
3. Change HttpTransportSE to HttpsTransportSE
4. Use Thread or AsyncTask
5. For handle SoapAction use Ksoap 3.0.1

Complete code is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sonuc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tableName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tableName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    request.addProperty("tableName", tableName.getText().toString());
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
                    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
                    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    try {
                        HttpsTransportSE transportSE = new HttpsTransportSE(DOMAIN,443,"/IntSecureFlight/SFInternal.svc",1000);
                        transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
                        Object result = soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                        if(result instanceof SoapFault12){
                            SoapFault12 soapResult = (SoapFault12) result;
                            message=soapResult.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }else if(result instanceof SoapObject){
                            SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) result;
                            message=soapResult.getProperty(0).toString();
                        }
                    } catch (SoapFault12 e) {
                        message = e.getMessage();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        message = e.getMessage();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        message = e.getMessage();
                    }

                    return message;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    sonuc.setText(message);
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }


            }.execute();

    }
    });
}
```